# Basic integral proof

Tags: definite-integrals

I have the following statement:

> Prove that if $f$ is continuous then $\int_a^b{f(-x)dx}= \int_{-b}^{-a}f(x)dx$

My attempt was:

Starting from LHS, Let $u=-x$ therefore i have $-\int_{-a}^{-b}f(u)du=\int_{-b}^{-a}f(u)du$. But from here i don't know how to back to $x$.

Comment: $x$ and $u$ are "dummy" integration variables.  Doesn't matter what you call the integration variable...you can call it $x$ or $u$ or $z$ or anything else you like.

Comment: well, but $x = -u$ therefore $-f(u)du$ will be equal to $f(x)dx$ only if $f$ is odd because i will have $f(u)du = -f(-x)dx = -(-f(x))dx = f(x)dx$ But $f$ is not necessary odd

Comment: That was one substitution, but now forget that and make the substitution $u=x$.  Suppose you were just handed the integral $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx$.  Would you not agree that this is the same as $\int_a^b f(u)\,du$?  The integral doesn't "remember" the prior substitutions.

Comment: @lulu Well, i understood that is a dummy variable like $j$ in $\sum_{j=0}^n j$ in this case the role of $j$ is be a counter, but what is the role of $x$ in this case of the definite integral?

Comment: It's the same.  It's just an index that tells you haw to run the integral.  If you prefer you can write the integral as the limit of a sum...in that case the dummy variable will be exactly of the form you understand.

Comment: @lulu so, why don't write $\int_{a}^b f dx$?

Comment: What's the difference?  You still have the dummy variable $x$.

Comment: Well, is shorter. By the other hand, you know or have some links to investigate why and from where $dx$ appears? what is its equivalent in the limit notation of the definite integral?

Comment: In the limit definition, whichever one you had in mind, you consider a number of values in the range and consider $f$ evaluated at each.  $x$ then just represents the values you choose.

Comment: Should stress:  I am not trying to defend the notation for the integral.  There are lots of reasons to be unhappy with it (not least because "$dx$" is unreasonably mysterious).  I'm just describing how it works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you have some text that speak about the $dx$ in definite integration? I couldn't find any associated question in MSE

Comment: I don't, no.  I would suggest not getting too hung up on the notation.  We use a lot of that notation for historical reasons and would probably not choose it today.

Comment: Oh, thanks lulu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are handling *definite* integrals. Therefore, as lulu mentions in a [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3843689/basic-integral-proof#comment7928706_3843689), the dummy variable does not affect the value of the integral:
$$
\int_a^bg(x)dx=\int_a^bg(t)dt=\int_a^bg(y)dy=\int_a^bg(z)dz=\cdots
$$

---

\begin{align}
\int_a^b f(-x)dx&=\int_{-a}^{-b}f(u)(-1)du\\
&=\int_{-b}^{-a}f(u)du\\
&=\int_{-b}^{-a}f(x)dx
\end{align}

---

According to your [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3843689/basic-integral-proof/3843699#comment7928719_3843689) above, you seem to have confusion with indefinite and definite integrals.

If you set $u=-x$, then formally,
$$
f(-x)dx = -f(u)du\tag{1}
$$
In this case, $u$ is a function of $x$, and (1）is an identity of differentials.

One the other hand, when you write
$$
\int_a^b f(-x)dx=\int_a^b f(-u)du\tag{2}
$$
both $u$ and $x$ are dummy variables for the definite integral. There is no relation between them.

Comment: Well, i understood that is a dummy variable like $j$ in $\sum_{j=0}^n j$ in this case the role of $j$ is be a counter, but what is the role of $x$ in this case of the definite integral?

Comment: @EduardoSebastian: it is easier to see this by looking at examples than talking about it abstractly. Consider $\int_0^1x^2dx$ and $\int_0^1y^2dy$. In general, you can look at the fundamental theorem of calculus: $\int_a^bf(x)dx=F(b)-F(a)$. There is no variable on the RHS.